# drupal form_state при ajax post запросе

Tags: drupal

Есть стандартный запрос, типа

```
$.post('my_url',{'var1':'value1','var2':'value2'},function(data){
//обработка даты
}
```

И стандартная функция, которая ловит это дело:

```
function myfunc(){
  if(!empty($_POST['var1'])){
    //обработка поста
  }

}
```

Объявленная через коллбэк:

```
$items['my_url'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'myfunc',
    'access callback' => true,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);
```

Вопрос: как неправославный `$_POST` переписать через православный `$form_state`?
Пост приходит, форм стэйт, очевидно, пустой: формы-то соответствующей нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter_xss(trim($_POST['var1']))
```

мне в помощь. И пост сразу станет православным.